# NSUserNotificationCenter delegate not work when the app is not focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsusernotificationcenter

I have the code like this.

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
```

Also, I implement userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:. It works fine. However. when the app's window is not focused, this delegate method is not called, and the notification always present.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should set the delegate *before* you send the `-deliverNotification:` message.  If you don’t, it’s possible that your delegate method won’t be triggered even when it’s supposed to be.

Second, in the [documentation for `-userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), it states:

> ### userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:
>
> Sent to the delegate when the user notification center has decided not to present your notification.

i.e. you will *only* see this method invoked when `NSUserNotificationCenter` has already decided *not to* show your notification.  If it has decided that it *should* show it, it won’t bother asking.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this answer.